# Jenkins port incorrect from API

Tags: jenkins

I want to run Jenkins on a non-default port, so I modified Jenkins.xml like this:

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=1010</arguments>
```

It works properly from http://servername:1010 (and not from http://servername:8080) but the API (http://servername:1010/api/json?depth=1) still reports the path to the jobs on port 8080. (i.e. "url":"http://servername:8080/job/NameOfTheJob/)

I am running Jenkins version 1.632 on Windows, and have stopped/started Jenkins after making the configuration change, as well as rebooted the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to re-configure the base URL in the Jenkins configuration. Under *Manage Jenkins* -> *Configure System* -> *Jenkins Location*, set the **Jenkins URL** to the appropriate value. In my Jenkins (1.609.1), applying the change was enough to fix the REST API results (no reboot was necessary).

Comment: This corrected the problem, no reboot was required for me either.